# How to implement "group_by" functionality

Tags: python, sql, ruby-on-rails, algorithm, data-structures

In many functional languages like Python, Ruby, or SQL, we can use a pre-defined "group_by" function or method. If I want to implement this using Java, C, or something else that does not have "group_by" implemented by default, what would be the best way to do it?

Input: [ Key, Value ]

```
{ [ 'A', 1 ], [ 'B', 3 ], [ 'C', 1 ], [ 'A', 2 ], [ 'A', 6 ], [ 'B', 7 ] ... }
```

Output:

```
{ [ 'A', [ 1, 2, 6 ] ], [ 'B', [ 3, 7 ] ], [ 'C' [ 1 ] ], ... }
```

Sample code:

```
for element in "input": 
        for temp in "input":
            if ( temp.key == element.key )
                Output . getKey( element.key ) . addValue( temp.value );
            end if
        end for
end for
```

This code seems to be the common way to approach it, but does anyone have an idea better than this?

I'm assuming the array is not sorted, though it would be very easy. And, sometimes it is required to *NOT* modify the input, so what would we do? Copying the entire input data seems to be one solution but it would cost a lot of memory.

A hash table can solve this problem, and I believe this is the most common way to do it with O(n) space complexity and O(n) running time complexity.

Comment: Are your inputs objects/structs or arrays or hashmaps?

Comment: I'm not sure really what you're going for here, but from the input/output, I don't think that group by function exists in python -- You'd have to implement it yourself, probably using `defaultdict(list)` -- which is probably how I would implement it in other languages as well -- Some sort of hash table mapping values to some sort of list structure which supports appending.

Comment: @ Artjom B. It doesn't matter array or hash function related structure. Let's assume it's array (2d array)

Comment: @ mgilson I agree. it probably doesn't exist in python. But the idea I listed here is, python have very fancy helper functions to handle list, tuple, ... which mean, very easy just extend it. The idea here is, really just trying to discuss from the bottom, without any helper function to achieved that. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In Python you can use a dictionary:

```
input = [('A', 1), ('B', 3), ('C', 1), ('A', 2), ('A', 6), ('B', 7)]

output = {}
for key, value in input:
    if not key in output:
        output[key] = []
    output[key].append(value)
```

Comment: thank you. your method depends on list in python has hash table feature. Without hash table feature, the logic actually same as mine. But thanks for point it out.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right, a general approach would be this, which is easily adaptable to almost any language.

Python:

```
def group_by(arr):
    arr.sort()
    newarr=[]
    temparr=[]
    k=""
    for i in arr:
        if i[0]!=k:
            if len(temparr)>0:
                newarr.append([k,temparr]) # newarr = newarr + [k, temparr] also works
            k=i[0]
            temparr=[i[1]]
        else:
            temparr.append(i[1])
    newarr.append([k,temparr])
    print(newarr)
```

Comment: Thank you. That's one way to do it -- Sort. Thanks for point it out. In addition, can i ask, if the input is not allow to modify. what would you do? (I agree copy the entire data is one way to do it, but wasted so much memory)

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. What do you mean "the input is not allowed to modify"?

Comment: I mean, the input data is not allow to edit (immutable).

Comment: Why would you have an immutable list? In case you do, you run an item_by_item transfer to a new list. newlist=[], for i in arr: newlist.append(i)//newlist.sort() and work with it